# How to enable Google Sheet Script to work on Mobile?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope you can help.
I have set up a google Sheet script that merges and fills the cell once the button is clicked (registration schedule).

It works fine on the desktop, however, when I open the sheet on iOS Google Sheets app and click on the button it only selects the item.

Do I need to enable it to be live on mobile? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only functions that can be triggered on mobile are onEdit() and onOpen() functions.

However, here is a [workaround](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app) that you can try.